# How to show that taking away one point from interval can't split the interval into 4 distinct intervals?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose a continuous function $f:M \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ with M connected.

- Therefor $f(M)$ is connected, e.g. $f(M)$ is an interval.

Now we assume that $f(M \setminus \{0\}) = I_1 \cup I_2 \cup I_3 \cup I_4$ with $I_j$ intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ for $i \ne j$.

My claim is that this is not possible. With the simple explanation that there are at least three points "missing" between each pair $I_i$ and $I_j$ and we removed one at most, only if $\nexists \xi \in M$ such that $f(\xi) = f(0)$ and $\xi \ne 0$.

**-Is this statement even true?**

If so, I'd appreciate a proof for this.

Edit: In my case this function is also bijective, but it seems to me as we don't need this property to show this behavior and so I'd like not to rely on it.

Comment: In fact this is well possible. What you are talking about is that the pairwise intersection is empty, i.e. $I_i \cap I_j = \emptyset$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq 4$. However, $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap I_3 \cap I_4 = \emptyset$ might well be true, even if you only removed a single point...

Comment: Oh you're right...wasn't what I wanted to actually say. I'll edit this.

Comment: You could count connected components, which might give a more convincing proof.

Comment: It seems like you trying to show that a plus sign cannot be embedded into the reals?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sry? No I just want to show that if we take away a single point from the value set, the image set can't split into four distinct connected set, when it was connected before...If the question is ambiguous please tell me so

Comment: Bijection is needed.  If f (a) = f (0), then f (M) = f (M\{0})  is possible.